# Changing strokestyle to no for all point layers in group or project

Tags: pyqgis, symbology, for-loop

I have 700+ point layers in my project in one group ('Groupname'). All of them have the standard symbology (but different colors). I want to change just the setting of the "stroke style" to "no", but all different colors and other settings should stay the same.

I think it must be something like this:

```
layers = iface.mapCanvas().layers()
for layer in layers:
    single_symbol_renderer = layer.renderer()
    symbol = single_symbol_renderer.symbol()
    symbol.symbolLayer(0).setStrokeStyle(no)
#Refresh
layer.triggerRepaint()
iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology(layer.id())
```

Can you help?

Comment: First of all, you're mixing programming languages there. the `void` and `::` syntax are not used like this in Python, if they exist at all.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I changed my prediction of code, but still have no clue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
# reference to the project
p = QgsProject.instance()

# reference to the layer tree
root = p.layerTreeRoot()

# reference to the particular group
group = root.findGroup('Groupname')

# loop through layers in group
for child in group.children():

    # get reference to the QgsVectorLayer that is represented by the QgsLayerTreeLayer
    layer = child.layer()

    # optional check for geometry type
    if layer.geometryType() == QgsWkbTypes.PointGeometry:
    
        # reference to the layer's renderer
        r = layer.renderer()
        
        # reference to the renderer's symbol
        sym = r.symbol()

        # get the first symbol layer from the symbol (should only be one if you are using the default single symbol style)
        sym_layer = sym.symbolLayer(0)

        # remove the stroke
        sym_layer.setStrokeStyle(Qt.NoPen)

        # propagate changes to the QGIS GUI
        layer.emitStyleChanged()
```